# Trying to understand expectation and density functions

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, summation, expectation

Is it accurate to say that the probability density function is the function that dictates how likely any particular value is to be taken on by a random variable? For example if $f(x)$ is the pdf, then $f(k)$ is the probability that the random variable takes on the value $k$?

For example for a single fair die, there are only 6 values to take on, so $E(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{6} x f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the probability density function of a fair die, would it just be $f(x) = 1/6$?

And let's say it was a uniform distribution where values range anywhere from $4$ to $11$. Then it would be an integral right, because it can take on any value (not just discrete) between them? $E(x) = \int_4^{11} x f(x)dx$? But then how do I know what $f(x)$ looks like?

(I am trying to derive this intuition / figure out the correct formulas to learn better, so please don't link me to Wiki or something)

Comment: To be precise, only the second example is a density function  The first example is a probability **mass** function.  A mass function gives you probabilities directly, as you speculate in your first paragraph.  However, for a density function, $f(k)$ describes the probability of being "near" $k$: for instance the probability that the random variable falls in the range $[k,k+0.001]$ would be around $0.001 f(k)$ (hence the term "density").  For a distribution described by a density function, the probability of being exactly equal to $k$ is $0$.

Comment: Wait what? Why aren't they the same thing if one gives you the actual prob and one is just "near" it? What is the density function then for the die example if what I mentioned was the mass?

Comment: Is my usage of $f(x)$ incorrect in my first example then? Can you explain the p. mass function and the p. density functions for both the die and the uniform example?

Comment: The die does not have a density function, and the uniform distribution does not have a mass function.  The two concepts are not interchangeable: generally when a variable is governed by a pdf then it simply cannot be adequately described by a pmf, and vice versa.  One obvious difference: a probability density function is allowed to be $>1$.

Comment: So is the pmf more of a discrete version, pdf more of a continuous version? Why can it be >1?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the distinction.  For an example where a distribution function is $>1$, take the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,0.01]$.  The pdf is equal to $f(x) = 100$ for $0\le x \le 0.01$ (and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ outside this range).  This large density reflects the fact that all the probability space is packed into a small interval.  Hopefully this example makes it obvious that a pdf is not returning probabilities, but density of probability.

Comment: I suppose the point of "density" is to make it integrate-able. But are they both used as $f(x)$ in the $E(X)$ formulas just the same?

Comment: One fully mathematical answer is that $f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} P(X \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon))/\epsilon$, at "most" points (specifically, almost every point with respect to Lebesgue measure). (Note that the division by $\epsilon$ means that a pdf can be huge; it needn't be bounded by $1$.) Unfortunately "most" is weaker than you might expect; for example, you can have a pdf where this equality fails at every rational point.

Comment: (Cont.) One nice property is that if $f$ is continuous at a certain point then this equality is automatically satisfied at that point. Thus for example the usual pdf of the normal distribution is "meaningful" at every point; the usual pdf of the exponential distribution is "meaningful" at every point except $0$; the usual pdf of the uniform distribution is "meaningful" at every point except the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: If you are dealing with a rv $X$ that has PDF $f$ then for every measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ we have $\Pr(X\in A)=\int_Af(x)\lambda(dx)$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesguemeasure on $\mathbb R$. If you are dealing with a rv $X$ that has a PMF $f$ then $\Pr(X\in A)=\int_Af(x)\mu(dx)$ where $\mu$ denotes a specific [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on the support of $X$. So in that sense PDF and PMF are sortlike.

Comment: What is a Lebesque measure?

Comment: @ArukaJ I think that my former comment is not (yet) within your mathematical scope. If it comes that far that [Lebesgue measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) have become familiar to you then possibly it is time to read my comment again. Telling you here about it goes too far.

Comment: @ArukaJ For purposes of intuition, you can ignore the parenthetical remark about the Lebesgue measure in my comment. It is merely clarifying what exactly I mean by "most".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to give you some intuitive explanations about density functions.
They will not substitute for what is in your textbook, but may help you
understand what is going on.
First, you must make a distinction between discrete and continuous distributions.

**Discrete:** Let $X$ be a discrete random variable taking on a finite or
countable number of values. Then, as you say in your first paragraph,
the probability distribution function (or PDF or point mass function or PMF) $f_X(k) = P(X = k).$
Also, $f_X(k) \ge 0$ for all possible values $k.$ 
Also, $\sum_{k \in S} f_X(k) = 1,$ where $S$ is the finite or countable
set of all posible values $k.%

Example: Suppose I toss a fair coin $n = 20$ times. 'Fair' means that
$p = P(Heads) = 1/2$ on each toss. And tosses are independent.
Then the number $X$ is 20 tosses has a binomial distribution. Then the PDF
if $X$ is $f_X(k) = {20 \choose k}/2^{20},$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 20.$
Obviously, $f_X(k) \ge 0,$ for all $k.$ And one can show that
$\sum_{i=0}^{20} f_X(k) = 1.$

If I want to compute the probability for a particular $k = 10,$ then
it is $P(X = 10) = f_X(10) = {20 \choose 10}/2^{20} = 0.1762,$ computed
in R statistical software as:

```
 dbinom(10, 20, .5)
 ## 0.1761971
```

Strictly speaking, probability for a discrete random variable is defined only for `points', values
$k = 0, 1, \dots, 20.$ I can ask for the probability of an interval,
such as $P(4 < X \le 15),$ but that is *not* really an interval, it is just shorthand for adding
up the probabilities for the individual values $5, 6, \dots, 15$ contained
in the interval.
With some work or with software one can find the required sum of
eleven probabilities to be 0.9882.

```
 sum(dbinom(5:15, 20, .5))
 ## 0.9881821
```

**Continuous:** For a continuous random variable, individual points do not matter
and only intervals have probability. Suppose you are interested in heights
of people. You carefully measure heights of 1000 people and make a histogram.
Smoothing off the histogram, you hope to get an idea how heights are
distributed in the population.

You might get a histogram like the one
below. The (slightly lumpy) dotted green line is a 'density' estimator. It is a particular way
of smoothing a histogram. Because experience has shown that heights are
frequently normally distributed, I also included the smooth blue curve,
which is the density function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu=68$ and
standard deviation $\sigma =3.5.$

[image]

Either curve could serve as a density function. I'll use the normal curve
because it has a formula you can find in your text and it's programmed
into R.

A density function $f_X(x)$ of a continuous distribution must have three
properties:

(1) $f_X(x) \ge 0.$ (You would never get a negative value
smoothing a histogram; none of the bars go below the axis.)

(2) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\,dx = 1.$ (The total area beneath the
density function is unity. The probability that a person has *some* height
is $1$.)

(3) $P(a < X \le b) = \int_a^b f_X(x)\,dx.$ In order to find the probability
of a particular interval, integrate the density function over that interval.
This is the area under the density curve between $a$ and $b$. So probability amounts to area under the density curve.

It does not make sense to ask for a probability such as $P(X = 70).$
We say that $P(X = 70) = 0.$
If we ask 'What is the probability a randomly chosen person is 70" tall,
we don't mean 70.00000" tall. We ordinarily mean "What is $P(69.5 < X \le 70.5) = ?$"

That is an interval, and we can evaluate its probability. Actually,
calculus doesn't work here, but there are ways to do the computation.
[Use software, or standardize and use a printed normal table.] In software
we get 0.0966. (In R `pnorm` stands for the normal cumulative distribution
function: $F_X(a) = P(X \le a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f_X(x)\,dx.$)

```
 pnorm(70.5, 68, 3.5) - pnorm(69.5, 68, 3.5)
 ## 0.09659231
```

Maybe only people 67" or shorter are allowed to pilot a particular type
of fighter plane with a small cockpit. What is the probability a
randomly chosen person for our population would qualify according to this
rule? We seek $P(X \le 67) = 0.3875.$ Or maybe, $P(X \le 67.5) = 0.4432.$

```
 pnorm(67, 68, 3.5)
 ## 0.3875485
 pnorm(67.5, 68, 3.5)
 $$ 0.4432015
```

*Finally,* you specifically asked about the continuous uniform distribution $Unif(4, 11).$
It's density function has a constant value $f_X(x) = 1/7$ for $x$ in $(4, 11)$,
and $f_X(x) = 0$ outside of that interval. Then it satisfies rule (2) above:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^4 0\,dx
 + \int_4^{11} (1/7) \,dx + \int_{11}^\infty 0\,dx = 0 + 1 + 0 = 1.$$

Also, for this uniform distribution, you will find that 
$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx = 7.5.$

[image]

**As requested:**  *R code for graph of uniform PDF.*

```
 curve(dunif(x, 4, 11), 3, 12, lwd=3, n=1001, ylab="Density", 
      main = "PDF of UNIF(4,11)", ylim = c(-.004, 1/7))
 abline(h=0, col="darkgreen")
 points(7.5, -.003, pch=17)
```

*R code for fake normal data, histogram, density estimator, PDF curve.*
First line randomly simulates a sample of 1000 from NORM(68, 3.5).
This will be somewhat different each time the program is run, so
histogram and density estimator  will differ a bit on each run.

```
 x = rnorm(1000, 68, 3.5)
 hist(x, br=25, prob=T, col="wheat", main="1000 Heights")
   lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="darkgreen", lty="dotted")
   curve(dnorm(x, 68, 3.5), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
```

To be fussy, the last line might have used mean and SD of the simulated
*sample,* but with 1000 observations sample mean and SD are pretty close
to population $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ so you might  not notice a difference:

```
   a = mean(x);  s = sd(x)
   curve(dnorm(x, a, s), lwd2, col="blue", add=T)
```

Comment: Where did you get $1/7$ from and how do you know it is correct?

Comment: The PDF can be viewed as a rectangle, base $(4,11)$ of length 7, so for area to be 1, height must be $1/7.$  $E(X) = 7.5$ is the 'balance point' of the rectangle: put a fulcrum at 7.5 and it balances.

Comment: So if we know the lower bound $x_1$ and upper bound $x_2$ of the uniform distribution, the height at any point is $\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}$?

Comment: Yes, any point between the bounds.

Comment: How did you make that wonderful graph?

Comment: @ArukaJ: I put R code for the graphs at the end of my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the probability density function, $f(x)$, of a cumulative distribution function $F(x)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, is defined as follows:

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\\
    &=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{P((-\infty,x+h])-P((-\infty,x])}{h},
\end{align}

where we assume $P$ is the probability measure generated by $F$. In the above definition, for a discrete distribution, $f(x)$ is not defined (the limit does not exist) for all $x$ belonging to the alphabet. For all other values of $x$, $f(x)=0$.

Thus, one does not define the notion of a pdf for a discrete distribution. As pointed out in the comments, the pdf can be $\geq 1$.

Comment: For a discrete distribution, $f(x)$ is undefined for the few values of $x$ taken by the random variable (the limit does not exist), and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: @ErickWong yes, you are right! I will modify the answer.